# Bluej is not pushing changes to gitlab repository

Tags: gitlab, bluej

another little issue with my current choice of IDE , Bluej. I have set it up to be able to share a project (namely to commit and push changes) using GIT,and specifically through a gitlab repository. 
After the first couple of successful pushes and commits(two weeks ago), I changed some code today, tried to do exactly the same procedure, and alas, the button OK in bluej to actually push the changes, is not active!
I have checked connection by entering password, all looks fine. Also, commits are happening fine locally, but when I try to push them through the TeamWorks of Bluej, the OK button remains inactive.

ps: a restart of the program did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case:

- switch to the command-line,
- go to your repository folder,
- and do a `git fetch` + `git status`

That should show you why a simple git push is not possible (possibly because you need to pull first)

Comment: HI @VonC, your comment led me to work through command line and fix the issue (well partly). Although it was only me working on the project, there was a need to do a pull first and then add>commit and push the changes. Having said that, BlueJ is still in denial and does not seem to work as it did the first time. I will un-share the project and do it once more.

Comment: Thank you, wouldn't do it without your prompt! I will update if I find a fix for the BlueJ side of things. thanks again.